# ¿Por qué el botón de un modal no efectúa la consulta solicitada?

Tags: java, primefaces

Al momento de presionar la tecla "enter", no me genera la descarga. Al contrario, realiza una nueva búsqueda.

Tengo un botón que me abre un `modal`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta ventana sirve para ingresar las credenciales para descargar un archivo .ZIP lo que pasa es que cuando presiono la tecla enter no me realiza la descarga.

al precionar la tecla enter pasa esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en lugar de realizar la descarga, me realiza una busqueda y no logro saber el porqué.

Código del botón (por si alguien me lo pide pero no creo que sea necesario):

```
 <h:commandLink style="margin-top: 10px;"   title="Adjuntar Fuentes Seleccionadas(.Zip)" disabled="#{empty busquedaBean1.fuente}" actionListener="#{busquedaBean1.abrirDialogo()}" >

        <h:graphicImage value="/img/ZipIconID.png" style="width: 60px; height: 60px; position: relative;" rendered="#{empty busquedaBean1.fuente}"></h:graphicImage>
        <h:graphicImage value="/img/ZipIcon.png" style="width: 60px; height: 60px; position: relative;" rendered="#{not empty busquedaBean1.fuente}"></h:graphicImage>
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:commandLink action="#{user.goLoginPage}"  />
```

Código que está llamando al dar click al botón:

```
  public void abrirDialogo(){
       if(!descargo){
           RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('IniciarDescargaFin').show();");
       }else{
           PruebaFinal();
       }
   }
```

Código del modal:

```
 <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="IniciarDescargaFin" header="Descargar" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">

                    <!-- Otro login para descargar -->
    <center><h:outputLabel for="username" value="Usuario:" /></center>
    <center><p:inputText styleClass="txtUsuario" id="username" value="#{busquedaBean1.usernombre}" required="false"  label="username" autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: lowercase;" /></center>

    <center><h:outputLabel for="password" value="Contraseña:" /></center>
    <center><p:password styleClass="txtPass" id="password" value="#{busquedaBean1.usupass}" required="false" label="password"/></center>
    <center><p:commandButton ajax="false"  id="loginSVN" value="Descargar" update="growl1" action="#{busquedaBean1.PruebaFinal()}" onclick="CerrarG()"/></center>

    <center><p:commandButton immediate="true"  value="Cerrar" update=":form" onclick="CerrarG()"  /></center>


 </p:dialog>
```

Comment: No veo en tu `dialog` un elemento `form`. ¿Están los elementos del diálogo dentro del `form` principal?

Comment: tengo 2 form pero no esta uno dentro del otro @SJuan76

Comment: si tuviera que agregar el form el codigo se haria mmas extenso

Comment: Puedes poner el código que descarga el archivo y ya verificaste que si esta entrando al metodo PruebaFinal()

Comment: el si entra al metodo siempre y cuando le de click al boton "descargar", pero al precionar la tecla "enter" pasa eso.@SoftMolina

Comment: osea el metodo de descargar funciona perfectamente, me refiero al momento de precionar la tecla "enter" es cuando falla @SoftMolina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que el problema se debe a que dentro de dialog no tienes las etiquetas **:form** para el mismo.

```
 <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="IniciarDescargaFin" header="Descargar"draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
     <h:form>
         <center><h:outputLabel for="username" value="Usuario:" /></center>
         <center><p:inputText styleClass="txtUsuario" id="username" value="#{busquedaBean1.usernombre}" required="false"  label="username" autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: lowercase;" /></center>
         <center><h:outputLabel for="password" value="Contraseña:" /></center>
         <center><p:password styleClass="txtPass" id="password" value="#{busquedaBean1.usupass}" required="false" label="password"/></center>
         <center><p:commandButton ajax="false"  id="loginSVN" value="Descargar" update="growl1" action="#{busquedaBean1.PruebaFinal()}" onclick="CerrarG()"/></center>
         <center><p:commandButton immediate="true"  value="Cerrar" update=":form" onclick="CerrarG()"/></center>
     </h:form>
 </p:dialog>
```

Espero te sirva mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: gracias :3 me funciono

Comment: haha de nada, un gusto ayudarte.